# Enable or disable target element based on checkbox checked state

Tags: javascript, html

i'm basically JavaScript newbie and I'm trying to resolve this problem of mine for quite a while. So,i'm doing JS school project and I need to make connection between checkbox and text form. If checkbox is not checked, text form should be disabled and vice versa. This is piece of code I have written:

```
function cbtf() {
    if (document.getElementById('checkbox').checked==false) {
        document.getElementById('textform').disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Can anyone write a new code ? That would be much of a help.

Comment: did it work? If not, what occurred?

Comment: Where's the HTML?

Comment: Please be more detailed about your problem - with examples and what you did, so others can help you.

Comment: @Terry - Why remove the snippet?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Because it doesn't result in a functional snippet. If it's just JS code then just leave it as a code block.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance - I suppose I was hoping it would become so :-)

Comment: This question is question or  copy paste?

Comment: <td>Osoba u pratnji: <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="cbtf()"   /> </td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Ime i prezime osobe:</td>
 <td><input type="text" size="20" id="textform"  /></td> This is a HTML code I have.

Comment: Tako update your question

Answer (score 1):

Simply attach a method to checkbox's onclick handler:

```js
function enableElement(id, enable) {
    document.getElementById(id).disabled=!enable;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    onclick="enableElement('textform', this.checked)" 
  />
  ENABLE
</label> 

<br/>

<textarea id="textform" style="width:100%; height:200px" disabled>
  THIS IS TEXTAREA WITH ID "textform"
</textarea>
```

or another simplification without creating special one-liner method - just define Your will directy in onclick event:

```html
<label>
  <input 
    type="checkbox"
    onclick="document.getElementById('textform').disabled = !this.checked" 
  />
  ENABLE
</label> 

<br/>

<textarea id="textform" style="width:100%; height:200px" disabled>
  THIS IS TEXTAREA WITH ID "textform"
</textarea>
```

Comment: That worked num8er,thank u so much <3 ! Thank you guys for help! Bear in mind that this is my first question on this site and sorry for stupidity on certain things !

Answer (score 0):

You won't get that to work unless you attach an event to the `checkbox`, so I would suggest something like this:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('textform');
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        textbox.disabled = false;
    } else {
        textbox.disabled = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: Probably want to listen to the `input` or `change` event ;) also, if the checkbox is going to be a toggle, then you need to add an `else` statement to (which re-enables the textbox) if it is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event to the checkbox, and assign it's check state to the disabled property of the TextBox.

```js
document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').onclick = function(e) {
  document.querySelector('input[type=text]').disabled = e.target.checked;
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="">
<input type="text" name="">
```